# Ionic Tab hidding back button

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I have an ionic tab and would like to hide the back button for one my tab. is it possible?
How about the entire tab but not the rest of my page?
If you look at the code I added "hide-back-button="true" when I want to disable it but obviously this doesn't work.

I would like to do something like this.

```
<ion-tabs menu-close class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top margin">

<ion-tab title="Top Picks" icon="ion-m-food" href="#/app/foodlist">   
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="Locations" icon="ion-m-map" href="#/app/map-view">  
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="Vendors" icon="ion-ion-chef" href="#/app/explore"  hide-back-button="true">   
</ion-tab>    
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your `# / App / explore`template html

ex. explore.html

add：

```
    <ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
```

like this：

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content>
    ...
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and keep `index.html` like this:

```
<ion-nav-view>

<!-- keep empty -->

</ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: this is helpful! Instead of the back button I have a menu button. currently with your solution it does remove the back button (which is great) but it also remove the menu button.
Now if I add the menu button directly into the explore template. it will not display it with `menu-toggle="left"` but does display it without it

Comment: <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
   <!-- Toggle left side menu -->
   <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

Answer (score 2):

You should make `hide-back-button` in your `ion-view` for that `ion-tab` as `true`.

```
<ion-view hide-back-button=true>
```

Check out [this](https://codepen.io/divyanshu013/pen/jyEywX) example on codepen.

Answer (score 0):

I had a tab with 3 page + a side menu.
So you recommendation helped and the final solution looks like this.

menu.html

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-ios-person-outline" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

For every page in the tab. I added

```
<ion-view hide-back-button=true>
...
<ion-nav-buttons side="left"> 
  <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-person-outline">
  </button> 
</ion-nav-buttons>
...
<ion-tabs menu-close class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top margin">
<ion-tab title="Top Picks" icon="ion-m-food" href="#/app/foodlist">   
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="Locations" icon="ion-m-map" href="#/app/map-view">  
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="Vendors" icon="ion-ion-chef" href="#/app/explore"  hide-back-button="true">   
</ion-tab>    
</ion-tabs>
```